# jQuery is not executing in React component

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am trying to use jQuery to remove and add a class in my React login component. When the code executes, it seems like the jQuery is just skipped over. I get no error messages and the jQuery functions do not run. Here is what my jQuery looks like in my React component method:

```
handleLogin(e) {
e.preventDefault();

const email = this.refs.loginEmail.value;
const password = this.refs.loginPassword.value;

auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(() => {
    Store.dispatch({type: 'LOG_IN', payload: true});
    history.push('/');
  })
  .catch(error => {
    $('.login-box').addClass('error-shake');
    $('.login-box').delay(200).removeClass('error-shake');
    throw new Error(error.code + ': ' + error.message);
  });
```

}

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

You're interfering with React rendering. React keeps a Virtual DOM and renders diffs of this VDOM to the document DOM. You're applying changes to the DOM that React does not know of and it will overwrite these changes once it rerenders the component. So in short: don't use jquery with React unless you know what you're doing. You can check these docs https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html to integrate with external libraries.